# How to fetch all subscribed Podcasts and not just downloaded ones, locally

Tags: objective-c, podcast, mpmediaquery, apple-musickit

I'm building an import method from the native Apple Podcasts app into my own.

So I've been using a predicate to fetch MPMediaItems of type Podcast from the local device, however, this (As shown below) only shows downloaded episodes and not shows:

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:MPMediaTypePodcast] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];

MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[query addFilterPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *items = [query items];

for (int i = 0; i<items.count;i++){
    MPMediaItem * item = items[0];
    NSLog(@"%@", [item podcastTitle]);
}
```

How do I fetch a users subscribed podcasts from their device using either a predicate or MusicKit?